# How can i pass arguments to main() function in c language?

Tags: c, atoi

I wrote a program for exercise 1-20 from the book the c programming language.

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi() */
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c,i,n;
    if (argv[1])
        n=atoi(argv[1]);
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if(c!='\t') {
            printf("%c",c);
        }else
        {
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i pass arguments to main() function in c language without the atoi() function?

Comment: Sorry, i will fix that.

Comment: `argv` is an array of pointers to zero-terminated strings. To pass arguments without the `atoi` function, just don't call the `atoi` function. OTOH, for exercise 1-20, the only argument is a number, which is converted from a string to an `int` by the `atoi` function. You need to decide what value `n` should have when the `if(arv[1])` check fails. A good choice would be 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All arguments to a program is passed as strings, with `argc` telling you how many there are and `argv` containing the actual arguments.

If you need a numerical value you have to somehow convert them, and you can use atoi as you have done, or use one of the many libraries to parse options, like [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

You should check `argc` instead of checking `argv[1]`, so

```
if (argc >= 2)
    n=atoi(argv[1]);
```

Have a look at [this](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) handy guide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Soren.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small program that prints all the arguments passed to your program, including the program name itself.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("Arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fjotten.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to main are the ones you pass in the commandline. Example: your binary is called a.out you would do:

```
./a.out 5
```

The argv Array would now have two (argc) entries: `[0] "./a.out"    [1] "5"`.

You should always Test if argc is big enough before accessing argv.

By the way: `atoi` does simply convert the passed  String (`argv[1]`) to an integer

Comment: Thanks for your reply mame98

Comment: No  Problem...  ;)